# Starting a build or debug task from inside a Visual Studio Code extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, task, vscode-extensions

I am looking to start a build or debug task from inside a Visual Studio Code extension. Is there currently a way to do this and if so, how?

Comment: Please provide your finding.